# Proving that the polynomial $10X^6-15X^2+7$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As stated, I am trying to prove that $10X^6-15X^2+7$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X].$

I have been given the hint to compare the above polynomial with $7X^6 - 15X^4+10.$

I know that $7X^6 - 15X^4+10$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ because of eisenstein's criterion for $p=5$, but I have no idea how one could prove that $10X^6-15X^2+7$ is irreducible because $7X^6 - 15X^4+10$ is irreducible. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+10X%5E6-15X%5E2%2B7+mod+11) tells us that $10X^6-15X^2+7$ is irreducible mod 11.

Answer (score 15):

**HINT:** If $f(x)$ is irreducible, so is $x^nf(1/x)$, where $n = \deg f$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $10X^6-15X^2+7=P(X)Q(X)$, where $P(X)$ and $Q(X)$ are non-constant polynmials, whose degrees are $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then $m+n=6$ and$$X^6P\left(\frac1X\right)Q\left(\frac1X\right)=7X^6-15X^4+10.\tag1$$But $X^6P\left(\frac1X\right)Q\left(\frac1X\right)=X^mP\left(\frac1X\right)X^nQ\left(\frac1X\right)$ and therefore $(1)$ expresses $7X^6-15X^4+10$ as the product of two non-constant polynomials.